# Taking action after some time. discord.py or disnake

Tags: python, discord.py, disnake

### Question:

How can I perform actions after a while? Let's say: if 60 seconds have passed, then the message is deleted, and something is also deleted in the database.

### Possible Solutions:

Make a message delete in the same slash_command, and then use the listener to catch the deleted message and change the database...

**If you have better options, please let me know.**

#### Possible Solution Example:

```
@bot.slash_commands()
async def sell(ctx):
    ctx.send("Bla bla bla", delete_after=60)

@bot.event
async def on_message_delete():
    ...
```

Comment: You can also use `asyncio.sleep()` to wait for a while. However, why would you want to use a listener to catch the message deletion? You're the one that's deleting it, you already have all the info available...?

Comment: I just need to delete the message after some event, and perform some action

Comment: But if you are the one deleting the message, why do you need to wait for the event? Can't you perform the action after deleting it in that command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...I am hoping that you are talking about a discord bot or a client here...
For deleting a message after a while you can use the following code:
I am sure that since you have mentioned the usage of a slash command, you would have used the "interaction" parameter in your function but just in case I shall give the code for ctx also...
if ctx:

```
await ctx.send("your message here", delete_after=60)
```

or if interaction:

```
await interaction.response.send_message("your message here", delete_after=60)
```

in the meanwhile you may have a listener going on as such:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    message_content=message.content
```

you can do any required functions with the message_content...
Hope this helps you!